# Javascript (node.js) array to specific string format (similar to JSON)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

All my digging and searching online did not result to find me right method to get the following string in required format, I can of course concatenate and achieve this in crude way, however I'm eager to learn Javascript + JSON. I'm using the string in node.js express basic authentication.

I need to build the following string (the one only inside the curly braces):

```
app.use(basicAuth(...
  users: { 'admin': 'adminpass' , 'user':'userpass'},.....
```

**Code to fetch the data from database:**

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM wts_users', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var result = results[i];
    userList.push(result.user_name, result.user_password)
  }
  console.log("user list: "+JSON.stringify(userList));
});
```

The result I'm getting:

```
["admin","adminpass","user","userpass"]
```

How can I get the result in the below format.

```
{ 'admin': 'adminpass' , 'user':'userpass'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `userList` as an object is the correct way. But if you already have an array and must necessarily convert it into an object, taking elements 2 by 2, you may use this function:

```
function toObject(arr) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2)
    obj[arr[i]] = arr[i+1];
  return obj;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
let result = ["admin","adminpass","user","userpass"]

function toObject(arr) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2)
    obj[arr[i]] = arr[i+1];
  return obj;
}

console.log(toObject(result));
```

Answer (score 3):

**userList** should be an object

```
userList = {};
userList[result.user_name] = result.user_password;
```

Alternatively, you can use **Array.reduce**

```js
let results = [{user_name: "admin", user_password : "adminpass"}, {user_name: "user", user_password : "userpass"}]

let userList = results.reduce((o, {user_name, user_password}) => Object.assign(o, {[user_name] : user_password}), {});

console.log("user list: "+JSON.stringify(userList));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the appropriate time to use `reduce`:

```
const userList = results.reduce((a, { user_name, user_password }) => {
  a[user_name] = user_password;
  return a;
}, {});
```